# TV stream url crawling

Tags: web, video, web-crawler

I would like to get the live video url from form here:

http://live.tvfix.org/play/jade

Could someone give me a direction how to do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

non-code way: you can use chrome extension which can record screen, than open live video in chrome, use that to crawl

use code: you can search about ffmpeg, ex "ffmpeg -f gdigrab -framerate 30 -i desktop output.mkv" in window command promt